# Solidity token contract function stops working when checking a mapping in if else statement

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, solidity-0.8.x

So I'm forking an ethereum token contract and I want to add the function that if you sell withing 24 hours you get taxed more than usual, I am using this logic for it

```
if(takeFee){
            // bot/sniper penalty.
            if(earlyBuyPenaltyInEffect() && automatedMarketMakerPairs[from] && !automatedMarketMakerPairs[to] && buyTotalFees > 0){

                if(!boughtEarly[to]){
                    boughtEarly[to] = true;
                    botsCaught += 1;
                }

                fees = amount * 99 / 100;
                tokensForLiquidity += fees * buyLiquidityFee / buyTotalFees;
                tokensForOperations += fees * buyOperationsFee / buyTotalFees;
                tokensForDev += fees * buyDevFee / buyTotalFees;
                tokensForBurn += fees * buyBurnFee / buyTotalFees;
            }
            
            // on early sell
            else if (automatedMarketMakerPairs[to] && sellTotalFees > 0 && ((_buyMap[from] + (24 hours)) >= block.timestamp)) {
                fees = amount * sellTotalFeesEarly / 100;
                tokensForLiquidity += fees * sellLiquidityFeeEarly / sellTotalFeesEarly;
                tokensForOperations += fees * sellOperationsFeeEarly / sellTotalFeesEarly;
                tokensForDev += fees * sellDevFeeEarly / sellTotalFeesEarly;
                tokensForBurn += fees * sellBurnFeeEarly / sellTotalFeesEarly;
            }

            // on sell
            else if (automatedMarketMakerPairs[to] && sellTotalFees > 0){

                fees = amount * sellTotalFees / 100;
                tokensForLiquidity += fees * sellLiquidityFee / sellTotalFees;
                tokensForOperations += fees * sellOperationsFee / sellTotalFees;
                tokensForDev += fees * sellDevFee / sellTotalFees;
                tokensForBurn += fees * sellBurnFee / sellTotalFees;

            }

            // on buy
            else if(automatedMarketMakerPairs[from] && buyTotalFees > 0) {

                if (_buyMap[to] == 0) {
                    _buyMap[to] = block.timestamp;
                }

                fees = amount * buyTotalFees / 100;
                tokensForLiquidity += fees * buyLiquidityFee / buyTotalFees;
                tokensForOperations += fees * buyOperationsFee / buyTotalFees;
                tokensForDev += fees * buyDevFee / buyTotalFees;
                tokensForBurn += fees * buyBurnFee / buyTotalFees;
            }

            if(fees > 0){
                super._transfer(from, address(this), fees);
            }

            amount -= fees;
}
```

The problem I have is that it all works when the user is buying but if he wants to sell he can't even tho he should only get taxed, not stop him from selling, this is the block of code responsible for the early sell taxing:

```
// on early sell
            else if (automatedMarketMakerPairs[to] && sellTotalFees > 0 && ((_buyMap[from] + (24 hours)) >= block.timestamp)) {
                fees = amount * sellTotalFeesEarly / 100;
                tokensForLiquidity += fees * sellLiquidityFeeEarly / sellTotalFeesEarly;
                tokensForOperations += fees * sellOperationsFeeEarly / sellTotalFeesEarly;
                tokensForDev += fees * sellDevFeeEarly / sellTotalFeesEarly;
                tokensForBurn += fees * sellBurnFeeEarly / sellTotalFeesEarly;
            }
```

If I take it out buys and sell work but if I put it back in it sells stop working, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, the error was that this "((_buyMap[from] + (24 hours))" should be this "((_buyMap[from] + (24 * 1 hours))"

Almost gave up on it, gotta love coding.